# Sequelize: use function in column query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write in sequelize the following SQL query:

`select * from properties where parse_input(address) LIKE parse_input('%some filter%')`

where `parse_input` is a function which I defined in my postgres DB. Basically I want to apply the same function to the filter and to the values and then run a `like` comparison.

I tried with something like:

`Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('parse_input', Sequelize.col('address')), '$iLike', Sequelize.fn('parse_input', '%some filter%'))`

I see the generated query:

`...AND "properties"."attribute" = parse_input("address") AND "properties"."comparator" = '$iLike' AND "properties"."logic" = '%some filter%';`

but I get a `errorMissingColumn` error.  Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
Sequelize.where(
      Sequelize.fn('parse_input', Sequelize.col('address')), {
        [Op.iLike]: Sequelize.fn('parse_input', '%some filter%')
      })
```